# Problems with txChart Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, tx

I'm having issues with this two lines:

```
const unsigned char* sendstring = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( "Hello" );
txChar.writeValue(sendstring);
```

is giving me this error:
`invalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]`

I was trying to convert the sendstring variable in the first line but no.

Comment: Why are you using a `const unsigned char*`? Would this work for you: `txChar.writeValue("Hello");`

Comment: Hi @M.Kotzjan it´s because it gaves me this error: `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Could you add your full sourcecode? It is unclear what type of characteristic txChar is

Comment: sure @M.Kotzjan here it is: [source](https://github.com/Ladvien/arduino_ble_sense/blob/master/ble_sense_33_test.ino/ble_sense_33_test/ble_sense_33_test.ino)

Comment: Is this your code or are you trying to modify it to send `"Hello"`? txChar is a `BLEByteCharacteristic` and is probably not what you want